# how to display files of a folder in listbox by browsing the folder using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
string path = TextBox1.Text;
DirectoryInfo dtr = new DirectoryInfo(path);
if (dtr.Exists)
{
    FileInfo[] files = dtr.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
    Label1.Text = "entered to listbox";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "directory doesnt exit";
}
```

I AM using asp.net,
i have a textbox,a button and a listbox,
i am copying  the path of  a folder in the textbox and on button click it display all the text file in the listbox.....
BUT, i dont want to copy the folder path to textbox rather i want to browse the folder on button click and it will display the path in textbox and on another button click it will display the files inside that particular folder

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
```

with

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name.Substring(file.Name.LastIndexOf('\\')));
```